# How to Prevent COUNTIF Function from Interpreting Text as a Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It seems that `CountIF` will return incorrect results if target array contains text that, inadvertently, looks like a date.  I've looked extensively for a solution, but have not even found anyone with the same problem.

To replicate the problem:

Cell `A1`: 10-1968 (as text, can precede by apostrophe)

Cell `A2`: =`COUNTIF(A1,"=10-68")`

Cell `A2` will return 1 because it interprets A1 as containing a date (Oct 1, 1968), even if it's formatted as text.  In my case, the value 10-1968 is Office #10, Project #1968 (and has nothing at all to do with dates).

I tried various combinations of the `TEXT` function and `LEFT` function with no improvement.  I think if it looks like a date, `CountIF` will see it that way.  How can I prevent this behavior?

Note: I do not want to use `SumProduct` or write a UDF.  And, I solved the problem with `MATCH` which returns `NA`, so needed to wrap that in `ISNA`.  But that makes for a much more complicated formula and I want to know how to solve this with ordinary use of `CountIF`.

Who knows when a string might look like a date?  This would seems to make `CountIf` unreliable to use unless there is a way to have it match only on an exact text match.

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do this without SUMPRODUCT and/or a helper column.

Comment: at least in google sheets, formatting the cell as plain text instead of automatic resolves the issue

Comment: change the format for the A1 cell to be 10+68 to avoid confusion with a date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"*10-68")
```

Using an asterisk wildcard `*` will get your `COUNTIF()` working. Magically it will get the right result. This seems a valid option in your situation since you'll only have two numbers in front of your first `-`. An asterisk in front of that wouldn't harm. It appears that Excel starts to only work with true text strings in the case of wildcard usage within `COUNTIF()`. I myself have no explaination for that.

Another option, as previously mentioned is using `COUNTIFS()` with the `?` wildcard combo, like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1,"10-68",A1,"??-??")
```

Example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`is:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"*10-68")
```

Or

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"10-68",A1:A5,"??-??")
```

Comment: Building on this, if one puts the lookup value in a cell, say C1 then this array formula will create the `??-??` based on the input: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,C1,A:A,CONCAT(IF(MID(C1,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(C1))),1)="-","-","?")))`  As it is only iterating the length of the string it is will not be too taxing on the calc. But it does require the CONCAT formula.

Comment: Clever!  But the format of the search string isn't limited to the format ??-??.  The second segment can be 1 to 4 characters.  Above from Scott is also clever, but that formula is a lot more complicated than the IF(ISNA(match....)) solution I found.  Goal of this post was to find a solution with "ordinary" use of CountIF that would be simpler than or equivalent to using Match.  But it seems Excel will interpret first as a date...seems odd to me that it does this.  Thx!

Comment: @ScottCraner, can you shine your light on the behaviour of using the `*` in my sample data? Why does this work?

Comment: @pghcpa if your only goal is to know if it is in the column and not the number of times then match is the best method. Of you want the count then yes countif has the draw backs you described. Excel is not a database and as such has it limitations.  There are work around described above but excel will assume if you want more functionality then one would use vba

Comment: @JvdV found the answer!  I'm not sure why preceding with asterisk works, but perhaps it forces Excel to evaluate the function as text instead of a date.   Great work, congratulations and thanks.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I'm well familiar with alternatives to CountIF and UDF's, but I try to find the simplest solution with the easiest formula to read.  I did not expect CountIF to default to evaluating a string as date if string happened to be a possible date.  So, was just looking for how to get expected behavior.   JvdV found it.  I wouldn't have thought of that.  Now that I see this behavior, agree Match is more reliable even if formula ends up more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using `=SUM(IF(A1="10-68",1,0))` entered as an array formula (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) will give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: This is in the same vein as SUMPRODUCT, an array type formula.  It is the same as `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1="10-68"))` It iterates and not what the OP wants.

Comment: The OP did not mention anything about array formulas.  `SUMPRODUCT` does not necessarily imply an array formula.

Comment: You are correct that it is my interpretation of the question.  BTW, your sum can be simplified: `=SUM(--(A1="10-68"))`  No need for the IF.

Comment: Thanks but as OP, I wrote: "I want to know how to solve this with ordinary use of CountIF."  I meant no other formula, UDF or array.  No array needed as problem solved by JvdV without one.  I continue to learn how to post questions with specific parameters, but difficult to list everything to rule out.  Appreciate the attempt, though.